# Jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith doesn't work with fetch API and URLSearchParams from es6

Tags: http, jasmine, tdd, fetch-api

I wrote a test for a POST call with Fetch API. To check if I send good parameters I user jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith and that's work fine with a string body.

When I change this string to URLSearchParams object from es6 not Angular. The test becomes red however the expected call and the call are exactly equals.

Have you got an idea?

Test:

```
...
mockHttp = {post: null} as Http;
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.set("refresh_token", token.refreshToken);
searchParams.set("grant_type", "refresh_token");
searchParams.set("client_id", "DriverApp");

expect(mockHttp.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ENDPOINT_API_URL_REFRESH_TOKEN", searchParams, {headers: headers})
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom equality tester of jasmine :

In the test file add this function :

```
function customEquality(expected: any, value: any): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(expected).trim() === JSON.stringify(value).trim();
}
```

In a beforeEach add this line: `jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester(customEquality);`

And use normally `toHaveBeenCalledWith`